# Displaying foreign key values using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables which are `states`, `cities`, `colleges`. All are contains id and corresponding names.
I have one more table `students` with column names are `id, studentname, state, city, college`.

Now i need to search how many students are from selected state/city/college, . sometimes i need to select multiple options like **state** and **city** but not **college** or state college but not city etc...

My query is:

```
SELECT `state`, `city`, `college`, `student name` FROM `students` where `state`='1' AND `city`='4';
```

It returns records but `state` `city` `college` columns will be foreign keys, i need to see city name but not city id, state name but not state id, etc..

Comment: What do state and city in the student table represent?

Comment: simply states table primary key and cities table primary key.

Comment: Yeah, but what is a state or a city in this context? Somewhere they live? Work? Study? How could the state and city combination be different from that of the college, say?

Comment: state table contains stateid, statename && city table contains cityid, cityname.
Student table contains records with date, cityid, stateid. I want to see all the records from student table based on selected city and selected state, in result i want to seen state name instead of state id, city name instead of city id.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense. The implication is that a city can belong to more than 1 state. This seems implausible

Answer (score 0):

use sql join assuming state_id, city_id, college_id are saved for each student for ex.

```
SELECT `states.*`, `cities.*`, `colleges.*`, `students.*` FROM `students` left join states on states.id = students.state_id left join cities on cities.id = students.city_id left join colleges on colleges.id = students.id where `students.state`='1' AND `students.city`='4';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response "Sam": I have tried your query as below, but it displays as "Unknown column 'states.*' in 'field list'".
"SELECT `states.*`, `student_results.*` FROM `student_results` left join `states` on states.id = student_results.state WHERE `state`='1' AND `city`='56'"